# Should const struct members change when sending it as a function parameter?

Tags: c, struct, constants

I have a struct:

```
typedef struct {
    int  age;
    char *Name;
    int  sex;
} PERSONAL_INFO;
```

I declare a struct using:

```
PERSONAL_INFO  *John;
```

and I want to send this struct into a function as a const bc I don't want any of the data to change.

```
void processInfo(const PERSONAL_INFO *person)
{
    //process information
}
```

Does this guarantee that the struct data members won't change? Or do I need to declare the data members as consts as well?

Comment: Your declaration isn't valid, since struct2 doesn't have a type, nor are you passing in a pointer, which you likely actually do. Now, there's a few possibilities as to why your struct is changing: a) You're misdiagnosing your problem. b) You cast away the const in your function and change the struct. c) You have undefined behavior somewhere in your code (e.g. memory corruption), and who knows what will happen after that. Post your real code and more relevant details, you're much more likely to get help.

Answer (score 1):

The `const` guarantees to the author of the function that they can't *accidentally* change any members.

There's no guarantee to the caller of the function that it *won't* change any members, as the function's author can deliberately remove the const-ness with a cast.

To the function's caller, `const` is more of a promise by the function than a guarantee by the compiler.

However, even though the function can't change the *value* of the member `Name` without removing the const-ness of the parameter, it's free to change the value of whatever it points to, e.g. `person->Name[0] = 0` is valid in any case.

If you want absolute guarantees, you can't pass the structure itself but need to use a (deep) copy of it.

Comment: "*Yes, the members can't change*" this in fact isn't correct. Please note this is C. See *dbush*'s answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32699669/694576

Comment: @alk That wording was a bit strong, so I rephrased.

Answer (score 1):

It makes it harder to change the members but it's not a guarantee.

If you do this:

```
void processInfo(const PERSONAL_INFO *person)
{
    person->age = 0;
}
```

The compiler with throw an error:

> error: assignment of read-only location

But if you do this:

```
void processInfo(const PERSONAL_INFO *person)
{
    PERSONAL_INFO *other_person = person;
    other_person->age = 0;
}
```

You'll only get a warning:

> warning: assignment discards qualifiers from pointer target type

And if you ignore this warning, it won't stop you from changing the field.

Comment: I see. Is there any way to prevent any of the data from changing? I wouldn't think I would declare all the members as consts within the struct or else there would be no way to set the members...

Comment: @user1224478: "*Is there any way to prevent any of the data from changing?*" Pass a copy?

Comment: @alk That addresses the `age` and `sex` fields, but unless a deep copy is done it doesn't protect the `Name` field.

Comment: @user1224478: "*I would declare all the members as consts within the struct or else there would be no way to set the members*" during initialisation also `const` members can be set.

Comment: Then pass a "deep" copy ... :-)